# image translation in Pytorch, using affine_grid & grid_sample functions

Tags: python, image, pytorch, image-rotation, affinetransform

I am going to move the image for 1 or 2 pixels, as I specified a small number (1.25 , 1.9) in the affine matrix.

BUT, the image is moved far far away, like hundreds of pixels:

[image]

( my input image is fully filled with yellow pineapples)

Below is a working example.

```py
import torch
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
import torch.nn.functional as F

rotation_simple = np.array([[1,0, 1.25],
                           [ 0,1, 1.9]])

#load image
transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(255),
transforms.CenterCrop(224),
transforms.ToTensor()])
dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(datasets.ImageFolder('/home/Pictures',transform=transform,), shuffle=True)
dtype =  torch.FloatTensor


i = 0
while i<3:
    img, labels = next(iter(dataloader))
    img = img#.double() # 有时候要转为double有时候不用转

    rotation_simple = torch.as_tensor(rotation_simple)[None]

    grid = F.affine_grid(rotation_simple, img.size()).type(dtype)
    x = F.grid_sample(img, grid)

    plt.imshow(x[0].permute(1, 2, 0))
    plt.show()
    i+=1
```

I wonder why does the function move the the image so far away instead of moving it for just 1 pixel in x and y direction.

Ps. Setting "align_corners=True" didn't help for this case.

Pps. My pytorch version is 1.4.0+cu100

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "unit of measures" for the grid and the affine transformation are *not* pixels, but rather normalized coordinates:

> `grid` specifies the sampling pixel locations normalized by the input spatial dimensions. Therefore, it should have most values in the range of `[-1, 1]`. For example, values `x = -1, y = -1` is the left-top pixel of input, and values `x = 1, y = 1` is the right-bottom pixel of input.

Therefore, translating by `[1.25, 1.9]` is actually translating by almost the entire image size. You need to divide the translation values by 2*`img.shape` to get pixel-wise translations.

See the doc for [`grid_sample`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#grid-sample) for more information.